# How to rank in SQL Server over entire resultset?

Tags: sql-server, rank

Saw similar RANK() questions, but I'm not sure how to set up the OVER part of it.

This is my current query, which sorts items by highest total descending:

```
SELECT c.CONTID, COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
FROM CUSTOMER c
LEFT JOIN CLOGS1516 h
ON c.SERIALNO = h.SERIALNO
LEFT JOIN CUSTUFLD u
ON c.SERIALNO = u.SERIALNO
WHERE EVTYPE = 1
AND DATEADD(minute, OFFSET, h.EVDATE) BETWEEN '2016-01-25' AND '2016-02-21'
AND u.VALUE LIKE 'Retail'
GROUP BY c.CONTID
ORDER BY [Total] DESC
```

Sample output from above is:

```
CONTID  Total
109     105
084     88
589     86
610     68
415     58
```

There are about 300 total rows returned. I'm now trying to "rank" each record based on their total in comparison to the other items. Not sure if I do that in the same query as above, or if it's a sub-query of sorts. My first time trying to do ranking within SQL itself as opposed to PHP-side.

Comment: Are you just looking for `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*))` ?

Comment: Looks like it! I added a "DESC" in there and that got me what I needed. I was mostly confused on where to actually put that line in. Took some trial and error but appears to be working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ZLK - RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*)) was what I was looking for. Added it in my SELECT line and it ranked appropriately.